# How to change properties of element in JSXGraph?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

Suppose, I have the following piece of code:

```
var brd2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box2', {boundingbox: [-8.75, 2.5, 8.75, -2.5]});
var ax2 = brd2.create('axis', [[0,0],[1,0]]);
```

How can I change second point of axis?
Something like ax2.setSecondPoint([2,0])?

In general, how can I set property of any element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axis has two properties which names are self-explanatory: point1 and point2.
You can use setPosition method on any of them, e.g.

```
ax2.point2.setPosition(JXG.COORDS_BY_USER,[2,0])
```

Now there is one catch: you will not see this change on the chart unless you set `needsRegularUpdate` property of the axis object to `true`. Finally, to refresh the chart you should execute `fullUpdate()` method on the board variable. The whole looks like this:

```
var brd2 = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box2', {boundingbox: [-8.75, 2.5, 8.75, -2.5]});
var ax2 = brd2.create('axis', [[0,0],[1,0]],{needsRegularUpdate:true});

ax2.point2.setPosition(JXG.COORDS_BY_USER,[2,0]);
brd2.fullUpdate();
```

References:

http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/symbols/JXG.Point.html#setPosition

http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Options (search for "special axis options")

Now to change properties like `fixed`, `visible`, etc. you should use `setAttribute` method (`setProperty` is deprecated). Example:

```
// Set property directly on creation of an element using the attributes object parameter
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', {boundingbox: [-1, 5, 5, 1]};
var p = board.create('point', [2, 2], {visible: false});

// Now make this point visible and fixed:
p.setAttribute({
    fixed: true,
    visible: true
});
```

Source:
http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/docs/symbols/JXG.GeometryElement.html#setAttribute

Last but not least a simple formula:

```
a + b = c
```

where:
a = using JavaScript debugging tools in browsers to investigate object properties
b = checking documentation for products you use
c= success :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to read documentation, but couldn't find that.

Comment: *d = provide a bunch of examples on the project website to all new developers to easily understand all available functions*